When will pwsh wrap an object as psobject?
I am learning about Extended Type System from MSDN, I've learned the fact that all objects in pwsh has intrinsic members like psobject, pstypenames etc. Does this implies all object in pwsh is [psobject]? If it does, why does -is [psobject] returns false for some object like a native number literal 123. And I noticed that the object that's not a [psobject] will be converted as [psobject] after being piped into a cmdlet. So there's yet another question, when will pwsh implicitly convert an object into [psobject]? And when do we need to explicitly convert to it?
1 -is [psobject] # False
1 | % { $_ -is [psobject] } # True

After finishing writing this question, I started thinking that those views like pstypenames and other intrinsic members are not part of the [psobject]? I am not sure just a guess. So are they more primitive things in pwsh that cannot be described by a type?
1 -is [psobject] # False
1 | gm -MemberType MemberSet, CodeProperty -Force # object views returned


The short answer is "whenever you use . or |"

@MathiasR.Jessen why not wrap them in the first place? performance consideration?


Does this imply that all objects in PowerShell are of type [psobject]?

No. PowerShell makes its intrisic members available on instances of any an all .NET types - although, perhaps confusingly, the intrinsic property that provides access to rich reflection capabilities, is named .psobject

When does PowerShell implicitly convert an object into [psobject]?

Note: Objects are never converted to [psobject], they are wrapped by instances of the latter.

When binary cmdlets produce (success) output, using the .WriteObject() method, each output object is invariably [psobject]-wrapped.

This does not apply per se to PowerShell code, i.e., not necessarily to PowerShell scripts and functions, both simple and advanced ones:

Expression output (e.g., 1 + 2), including method calls (e.g. [datetime]::Parse('1/1')), as well as such output relayed from other scripts / function is not [psobject]-wrapped.

By contrast, any script / function output that comes from binary cmdlets (those implemented as precompiled .NET assemblies, typically in C#) is again [psobject]-wrapped, which notably includes use of the - rarely needed - Write-Output cmdlet.



On the input side, an "untyped" ([object]-typed) parameter that is designed to also / primarily bind its value from pipeline input as whole objects (so-called by-value pipeline binding, via the ValueFromPipeline parameter -attribute property), receives [psobject]-wrapped input objects when the parameter is indeed bound via pipeline input in a given invocation, as opposed to binding by argument[1] (which isn't usually done for such parameters).[2] This applies to both binary cmdlets and PowerShell code (i.e. also to by definition then advanced scripts / functions).

It is perhaps for this reason that the vast majority of built-in cmdlets that have an -InputObject parameter, whose primary purpose is to facilitate by-whole-object pipeline binding, use [psobject] rather than [object] for "untyped" input; a notable exception is ConvertTo-Json.

In (non-advanced) PowerShell code, the [psobject] wrapping additionally applies to the automatic $_ variable, as well as to the objects enumerated by the automatic $input variable.




Note:

[psobject] is a helper type that is meant to be invisible, an implementation detail from the perspective of PowerShell code (as opposed to C# code that implements cmdlets).

You can test for their presence with -is [psobject], as you're aware, but that's normally not needed.

Also note that, confusingly, [pscustomobject] is the same type as [psobject], System.Management.Automation.PSObject, although only the former can be used in constructing custom objects via the [pscustomobject] @{ ... } syntactic sugar; for a discussion, see GitHub issue #4344



Unfortunately, the situational presence of [psobject] wrappers does on occasion result in different behavior, as detailed in GitHub issue #5579, which links to many other issues describing such bugs.



[1] A quick demonstration in PowerShell code: Define the following function:
function Test-PSObject { param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] $InputObject) process { $InputObject -is [psobject] } }.
42 | Test-PSObject outputs $true, i.e. the pipeline input object was [psobject]-wrapped, whereas
Test-PSObject -InputObject 42 indicates $false.
[2] The reason is that - unless you define your pipeline-binding parameters as array-typed and perform manual enumeration of these arrays - you won't be able to pass multiple input objects by argument - see GitHub issue #4242.

These things can be confusing with object hierarchies, but an integer is an object. Usually the output of commands like select-object are "pscustomobject".
1 -is [object]

True


1 | % gettype                   

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                    BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                    --------
True     True     Int32                                   System.ValueType


[pscustomobject]@{num=1} | % gettype                                                              

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object


[pscustomobject]@{num=1} -is [object]

True


[pscustomobject]@{num=1} -is [psobject]

True


While I believe in letting one's answers stand in the face of down-votes if one has double-checked that their claims are true and if one believes they may still help future readers, note that your answer doesn't address the OP's questions.
(I wasn't among the down-voters, but I also don't think your answer is helpful.)
